# Why don't missing template/components throw an error in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In `Ember.js` when I add a helper to a template that identifiers a component, template, or helper that obviously doesn't exist, why is no error thrown? Is it possible to make Ember throw an error either in the console or to the DOM for debugging?

Example, if I create a template which includes the helper `{{asdhoausdho}}`, no error is emitted and the page where that helper should appear is blank. This is more probelmatic with simple misspellings.

Comment: Because it could be a property of the context (controller/component).

Comment: @locks Aaah, okay. So then if I wanted to throw an error I could do so in the `unknownProperty` for Ember in whatever component I'm currently debugging?

Answer (score 1):

A potential reason is that the component can be populated dynamically using `component` helper.

```
{{component dynmicComponentName}}
```

When the component cannot be found anywhere nothing will be rendered. This is actually a nice approach to handle errors.